# Find $Y=X^2$ from given $f(X)$ and find the $\rho(x,y)$ correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I have a question.

\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1-x, &{0 \leq x \leq 1}\\
1+x, &{-1 \leq x < 0}\\
0  , &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This is the given pdf and $Y=X^2$ given also. I need to find $\rho(x,y)$ (correlation coefficient) and also check if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not. I can do these parts but I don't know how to find $f_Y(y)$ from given pdf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can do these parts but I don't know how to find $f_Y(y)$ from given pdf.

You can derive $f_Y(y)$ by a simple transformation:

$$f_Y(y)=\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}-1   \right]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1]}(y)$$

...but this is not needed to solve your problem.

Obviously $(X;X^2)$ are not independent because one variable is expressed in function of the other one.

To calculate their correlation coefficient just use the definition

- First calculate covariance

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

- then, in necessary, by definition

$$\rho_{XY}=\frac{\mathbb{Cov}[XY]}{\sigma_X\cdot \sigma_Y}$$

any needed quantity can be calculated starting from $f_X(x)$ without deriving expressly $f_Y(y)$

This because any quantity can be expressed in

$$\mathbb{E}[X^n]=\int x^n f_X(x)dx$$

---

After easy calculations you will see that $\mathbb{Cov}[X;X^2]=0$ thus you have to show that, anyway, they are not independent.

To show that these rv's are not independent consider that an alternative definition of independence is, $\forall x,y$

$$f(y|x)=f(y)$$

now consider that, $X \in[-1;1]$ and $Y \in(0;1]$ but when, for example, $|X|<0.5$ also $(Y|X)$ support changes thus, i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>0.5||X|<0.5]=0$$

which is different from

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>0.5]$$

that is positive. This is a clear contradiction w.r.t. definition of independence

In other words, the occurrence of $Y$ strictly depends on what happens in $X$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I totally understand how to find correlation coefficient. As you said there is no need to calculate $f_y(y)$. I was thinking to show that if they are independent or not not via $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ equation. But since there is no need to calculate f(y) for this question I don't know how to show that they are not independent. I also understand why they are not independent but is there anyway that I can show that they are not independent in a formal way? Thank you so much again, much appreciate.

Comment: @scancet0 : I did some edits in my answer.

Comment: I am going to prove it with $f(y|x) = f(y)$ equation. Because as you said this is also a feature of being independent. Also found covariance 0 and correlation coefficient became 0. ( no need to calculate variance for both x and y but I could also calculate them without finding $f_y(y)$)
Thank you so much for your clear explanations and helping. I really helped me both understanding more about topic and for the solution.

Comment: @scancet0 : you do not need to prove anything....  you know that $X,Y$ are not independent, thus a counterexample is enough